# Angular 2/Material: How to dynamically specify the content of <md-tab>?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to make different tabs for different content. So far I'm able to create the labels of the tabs in a dynamic way using ngFor and a unique pipe.2, but not the content. Is there some way to do this? I want to use a different component depending on the label that I'm using.

```
<md-tab-group >
  <md-tab *ngFor="let afd of afdeling | uniek" label={{afd.afdelingsNaam}}>

    Content
  </md-tab>

</md-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve dynamic labels using [one way binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax) `[]` as `[target]="expression"`:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let afd of afdeling | uniek" [label]="afd.afdelingsNaam">
    Content
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pwfLprBo0zTntmpAHJdO?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality. The `[label]` will evaluate the value/expression passed in to dynamically populate the label text in this case.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. This is helping a lot ! Still have the small issue that angular isn't recognising my HTML. For instance:

content: `<app-pediatrie></app-pediatrie>`

if I put that in the md-tab, he will just translater it as text.

Comment: Glad to help! That would probably need to be posted as a separate question. You'd need to provide the definition for your component as well as how the component is being declared/imported/exported. This `[]` one way binding would how to dynamically pass a value regardless of the implementation. Thanks!